# ZIP files created with GUI have more bytes than ZIP files created in a shell

Tags: file, zip

I created two *ZIP* files of the same directory. One with the GUI, the other with:

```
$ zip -r alpha_cmd.zip Alpha
```

The *Alpha* directory is 33.640 MB with 164 items.

The ZIP file created by the GUI is 2,100 bytes larger than the ZIP file created on the command line.

Why is the ZIP file created with the GUI larger?

*Note*: Even though the ZIP files have different sizes, when unzipped, each's directory has the exact same number of bytes. Basically, I'm very wary of possible inconsistencies introduced by managing my file system with the GUI and with shell commands.

Comment: One may have invisible files, the other not?

Comment: From this [SU answer](http://superuser.com/a/574035/11306) try `ditto -ck --rsrc --sequesterRsrc --keepParent folder folder.zip`

Comment: @Mark I forgot to respond. That "ditto" command does create the exact same file as Finder. And the ditto / zip / "Finder ZIP" files are all cross platform. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Zipping from the Finder adds a folder __MACOSX, invisible on Macs, that contains OS X resource forks like custom icons and such. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork):

> The resource fork is a fork or section of a file on the Apple Mac OS operating system used to store structured data along with the unstructured data stored within the data fork. A resource fork stores information in a specific form, containing details such as icon bitmaps, the shapes of windows, definitions of menus and their contents, and application code (machine code). For example, a word processing file might store its text in the data fork, while storing any embedded images in the same file's resource fork. The resource fork is used mostly by executables, but every file is able to have a resource fork.

Comment: Minor correction: it's not just resource forks, it's all kinds of file metadata that the zip format doesn't handle natively, encoded in [AppleDouble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleSingle_and_AppleDouble_formats) format. That'll include spotlight comments, tags, Finder flags, quarantine data, etc as well as resource forks.

Comment: And I was wondering what was the "__MACOSX" folder in most zips... The more you know, eh?

Comment: Another reference which might illuminate the answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107903/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-the-same-format-as-the-finders-compress-menu-item

Answer (score 4):

Even apart from the main cause in this case (Finder adding extra hidden stuff, as empedocle says), different sizes for ZIPs of the same data doesn't indicate a problem, when the size difference is a fraction of a percent.

Different ZIP implementations might have a different default compression level (tradeoff between CPU time and size saved), or just have different code that saves more or fewer matches, saving more or fewer bytes at the default compression level.

For example, [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) usually makes smaller `.zip` files than other ZIP programs. (And no, I'm not talking about its own `.7z` file format. It has a better plain-ZIP compressor, too.)

[zipcmp](http://nih.at/libzip/zipcmp.html) is a cmdline program that can compare ZIP files. It defaults to comparing just the ZIP directory, to check that all files are the same name, size, and [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check). If this is the case, both ZIP files are almost certain to have the same contents, but just compressed differently (if the compressed size differs.) As long as the ZIP files aren't damaged, of course. Use `unzip -t foo.zip` to test a ZIP file for decompression errors, non-matching CRCs, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't the __MACOSX folders affect the CRC calculation?

Comment: ZIP stores a separate CRC the un-compressed contents of each compressed file.  (So no, for two reasons: directories only contain other files, not a block of data of their own.  And two, the CRCs stored in the ZIP metadata are for the each file separately.)  So all the files that were the same between two ZIP files would match in CRC and decompressed size.

Comment: @PeterCordes The fact that different ZIP implementations can produce different file sizes is exactly what caught my attention. I knew that the shell executed "/usr/bin/zip". But since Finder gave me a different file size, I thought Finder used a completely different executable (and that was upsetting to me). If I knew how to su root and had some courage, as a test I'd move "/usr/bin/zip" to "/tmp", and then try a Finder zip (and it better issue an error). But, I've work to do and can't risk destabilizing my Mac!

Comment: The safest way to temporarily replace `/usr/bin/zip` with a different version would be `ln /usr/bin/zip /usr/bin/zip.standard;  mv new_zip /usr/bin/zip`.  That way, you always have a `/usr/bin/zip`, because you atomically replace the system implementation.  Also, the old version is just renamed, not moved to `/tmp` (which might possibly be on a different filesystem.)  To disable it, I'd just rename it to `zip.disab`, see if Finder breaks, then rename it back.  But zip-creation library functions are common.  Finder almost certainly doesn't fork / exec `/usr/bin/zip`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I get it about calling libraries instead of the executable. But, the executable would have been "/usr/bin/ditto", and not "/usr/bin/zip" anyway. The assistance from this forum is great. Thank you for your time and effort.